# SSRS BIDS 2008 Expression for percentage over GROUPED BY coloumns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids

[image]See below image.

In the % column I need total % for each of the 3 categories for Days (Project,RFC,Support) for that particular month.

For example:

for the first service under **'Project'** in April i would need (9.4/(9.4 + 0 + 1.8)) * 100

for the first service under **'RFC'** in April i would need (0/(9.4 + 0 + 1.8)) * 100

for the first service under **'Support'** in April i would need (1.8(/9.4 + 0 + 1.8)) * 100

This would give me total percentages for each category on days per month.

What is the expression i need to use in the 'expression' box in design view to cover all my services?

Second image (above) is the Expression I have tried to use but am getting #ERROR on all records

[image]

Comment: Have used the following now:

=Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name")

Seems to work although for some records where there is 0 for all 3 classifications it is randomly putting 100% on one, but in other examples is putting Nan

Comment: Using an If could do the work  =Iif(Sum(Fields!Days.Value,"Date_month_name")=0
,"-"
,SUM(Fields!Days.Value)/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name")